# Is XStream still active/supported?

Tags: xml, xstream

Does anyone know if XStream is still active/supported?

It looks relevant to what we are trying to do, but it appears there have been no new releases or web site updates (at http://x-stream.github.io/) for almost two years (since Dec 2008), therefore I was a bit suspicious ... wanted to check if this component is still in active use, or if there is something which has superseded it.

Thanks.

Comment: JAXB is the industry standard.  Check out the MOXy implementation:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Blaise, thanks, that sounds a better approach, looking into that now.

Comment: Feel free to contact me if you require more information:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/p/contact_01.html